# Dockerizing React-Express- MongoDB Atlas App with Docker-Compose and Proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a react-express app that connects to MongoDB Atlas and is deployed to Google App Engine. Currently, the client folder is stored inside the backend folder. I manually build the React client app with `npm run build`, then use `gcloud app deploy` to push the entire backend app and the built React files to GAE, where it is connected to a custom domain. I am looking to dockerize the app, but am running into problems with getting my backend up and running. Before Docker, I was using express static middleware to serve the React files, and had a setupProxy.js file in the client directory that I used to redirect api requests.

**My express app middleware:**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../../client/build')));
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../../client/build/index.html'));
  });
}
```

**My client Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

**My backend Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  backend:
    image: backend
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - mern-app
  client:
    image: client
    build: 
      context: client
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - mern-app
    depends_on: 
      - backend
networks: 
  mern-app:
    driver: bridge
```

I'm hoping that someone can provide some insight/assistance regarding how to effectively connect my React and Express apps inside a container using Docker Compose so that I can make calls to my API server. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any error? log? ... Anything will help us to identify the problem.

Comment: @usuario the only error message I'm getting is a "ERR NAME NOT RESOLVED" error in the browser console.